# How to filter items from firebase with react-redux-firebase

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-redux

I'm creating an app with `react-redux-firebase`. I have many 'items' in many 'categories'.

How should I display the correct items on a category page?

I can use `firebaseConnect` to sync them from Firebase and then filter them in `mapStateToProps` using the categoryId prop, but them I'm syncing all items when only those in a specific category are needed.

I can use `react-router`'s `getComponent` to create a category page component and wrap it with `firebaseConnect` each time the category page is displayed. That way `firebaseConnect` can use firebase queries to filter the items. However, when I do this I occasionally see items from a previously viewed category.

Do I need to combine both methods? Is there a better way?